# Python - code transformation from hexadecimal \XE1 to á (a with spanish accent)

Tags: python, hex, diacritics, spanish

#When I try to transform in my code the letters from hexadecimal code to Spanish accent didn´t work.

#My IDLE is Spider

## Table

[Transform to Spanish letters] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGcZQ.png)

#Example:
#Definition three examples of a txt or str with #Spanish chr:

```
line3='RODR\xCDGUEZ' #->str
line4='Vel\xE1squez' #->str
line5='Andr\xE9s C\xe1ceres' #->str
```

## --------------------------------

#Please could solve the problem, because the string is the same but the idle work in two different ways, aren't similar results.

### Case 1 Correct

```
line2='RODR\xCDGUEZ'
```

#Result in the Variable explorer
'RODRÍGUEZ'

### Case 2 Incorrect

#(with modify de str internal by code)

```
line='RODR=CDGUEZ'
```

#with "=" to will replace in the next command

```
line=line.replace('=','\\x')
```

#The result is without Í??

```
'RODR\xCDGUEZ'
```

#I don't understand why the idle now don't recognize
"Í" and maintain "\xCD"

#th

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Describe what "didn't work".  Please don't paste links to images of text.  Put the *actual text* in the question so it is readable and copyable.

Comment: Note that `\x` is *case-sensitive* when entering a string literal.

Comment: for example, this code work ok: this assignation of str it's ok the idle transform correctly. myStr1='RODR\xCDGUEZ Vel\xE1squez L\xF3pez_Palma_Pablo_Marcelo'

Comment: Fine, but what doesn't work OK?  Again, `\x` is *case-sensitive*.  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75584113/edit) instead of putting new information or code in comments.

Comment: However whe I try to work with this code in the idle isn't work: line='=?Q?RODR\CDGUEZ?'

Comment: Thanks @markTolonen !! I proved with \x and \X and the result is different with \x its correct. My problem is about the kind of input of "str" for one side work and for another side didn't work. Define the str[ line2='RODR\xCDGUEZ'] and run the idle the result in the "explorer variable" and it's result its correct [RODRÍGUEZ]. However, if I insert [line='RODR=CDGUEZ'] and with code I change the "=" for "\x" with replace operator [line.replace('=','\\x')]. In the "explorer variable" appear [line='RODR\xCDGUEZ'] and didn´t translate to this word [RODRÍGUEZ]. Sorry if I don't express correctly –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate an escape code by simply building a string that looks like one.  Additional steps are needed to convert the string to a `bytes` object and then the manually constructed escape codes can be decoded:

```py
>>> s = 'RODR=CDGUEZ'
>>> s.replace('=','\\x').encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
'RODRÍGUEZ'
```

I *think* what you really have is an (incomplete) email header, as that uses the `=hh` notation for encoding non-ASCII data bytes.  The missing information is what encoding the bytes represent.  Below shows a valid encoded email header:

```py
>>> import email.header
>>> for value, encoding in email.header.decode_header('=?iso-8859-1?q?RODR=CDGUEZ?='):
...    print(value.decode(encoding))
...
RODRÍGUEZ
```